# How to create a nice box

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I want to create a nice box like the one in the image below. I tried to use this link: [title style in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271821/title-style-in-tcolorbox)

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sense of what you've tried? Something the community can work with as a foundation?

Answer (score 8):

Some thing like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\tcbset{examplebox/.style={enhanced,colback=white,colframe=green!65!black,
enlarge top by=10mm,
overlay={%
\path[fill=blue!65,line width=.4mm] (frame.north west)--++(17mm,0)coordinate(n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(-20mm,0) arc (-90:90:-4mm)--cycle;
\node at ([shift={(5mm,4mm)}]frame.north west){\color{white}{\textbf{\sffamily EXAMPLE}}};
\path[fill=green!65!blue] ([xshift=.4mm]n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(7mm,0)--++(0,-8mm)--cycle;
\node at ([shift={(4mm,4mm)}]n2){\color{white}{\textbf{\sffamily \themycounter}}};
\node at ([shift={(18mm,4mm)}]n2){\itshape\textbf{\sffamily Solution}};
}}}

Some text before ...
\begin{tcolorbox}[examplebox,step=mycounter,label=one]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
a lot of text here ... This is Example \ref{one}
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text after ...

Some text before ...
\begin{tcolorbox}[examplebox,step=mycounter,label=two]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
a lot of text here ... This is Example \ref{two}
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text after ...

\end{document}
```

You can use the feature-rich [`tcolorbox` package](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) with your own style. You should add the `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` library to be able to add custom `TikZ` `overlay`s using the `\tcbset{examplebox/.style={...}}`. You will also need a `\newcounter` to automatically number your example solutions. This is achieved by:

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
```

and in the options for `tcolorbox`, add `step=mycounter,label=<...>` for cross referencing. Therefore, In your style definition, put the `\themycounter` command in place of the example number.

Comment: Shouldn't you have  `\refstepcounter`, so that cross references work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thank you for the suggestion, I updated my answer accordingly.